# Service that creates a button on top of other applications and use OnClickListener

Tags: java, android-studio, service, onclicklistener

I'm working on a project and i aim to create a button that display on top of other applications and when we click on it, would change the activity on the screen, for this i made researchs and found that i had to use a "Service".

I managed to create an imageView that is on top of other applications but i cant interact with it and use an OnClickListener.

If you got any idea let me know please !

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)){
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Activity context = this;
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    Button start_button = findViewById(R.id.start);
    start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent startBubble = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BubbleService.class);
            startService(startBubble);

        }
    });
}
```

And here is the Service :

```
public class BubbleService extends Service {

private WindowManager windowManager;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    ImageView mFloatingImage = new ImageView(this);
    mFloatingImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    mFloatingImage.setClickable(true);

    int LAYOUT_FLAG;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
    } else {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
    }

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(150,
            150,
            LAYOUT_FLAG,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;
    params.gravity = Gravity.END | Gravity.CENTER;

    windowManager.addView(mFloatingImage, params);

    mFloatingImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("clicked");
        }
    });
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It is not going to work if you are using the flag below:

> WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE

Try to remove that flag and it should work.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help after trying to remove this parameter `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` it still didnt worked and when i try to remove `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` aswell, it detects click but even when im clicking at random places on the screen...